# How to use a Form to Append a row to a table with Access 2010

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to create a simple "Add Record" form into my database.  This is to add a NEW recordset.  This data will need to be duplicated/added across three tables (although right now I am struggling to get it added to one table!

I have tried using an Append Query, but it will not pull the data from the form into the appended record.  Here is my attempt at append query:

```
INSERT INTO Log ( State, Jurisdiction, Company, DueDate, Preparer )
SELECT Log.State, Log.Jurisdiction, Log.Company, Log.DueDate, Log.Preparer
FROM Log
WHERE (((Log.State)=[Forms]![NewEntry_Form]![TxtState]) AND
((Log.Jurisdiction)=[Forms]![NewEntry_Form]![TxtJurisdiction]) AND 
((Log.Company)=[Forms]![NewEntry_Form]![TxtCoNo]) AND 
((Log.DueDate)=[Forms]![NewEntry_Form]![TxtDueDate]) AND 
((Log.Preparer)=[Forms]![NewEntry_Form]![TxtPrep]));
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong.  Would it be easier to write a VBA script to insert a new record then immediately update that record with the information from the form?

Thank you! I am very new at this.

Sarah

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing is inserting a record from log into log if that record matches your form. Try this:

```
Sub InsertRecord()
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = ""
    SQL = SQL & "INSERT INTO Log ( State, Jurisdiction, Company, DueDate, Preparer )" & vbCrLf
    SQL = SQL & "VALUES ("
    SQL = SQL & Me.TxtState.Value & ", " & vbCrLf
    SQL = SQL & Me.TxtJurisdiction.Value & ", " & vbCrLf
    SQL = SQL & Me.TxtCoNo.Value & ", " & vbCrLf
    SQL = SQL & Me.TxtDueDate.Value & ", " & vbCrLf
    SQL = SQL & Me.TxtPrep.Value & ")"
    CurrentDb.Execute SQL
End Sub
```

Comment: It ALMOST works.  Access isn't recognizing the Form as place to pull information from.  Is there a way to create a *temp* table/Query result and use that information to append to the main table?

Comment: I changed my code. Run this on an event in your form.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using VBA

```
Private Sub CmdAdd_Click()
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO FileInfo(Company, State, Jurisdiction, Taxtype,     acctno, frequency, filemeth, pymtmeth, month, duedate, preparer, reviewer) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.TxtCoNo & ",'" & Me.TxtState & "','" & Me.TxtJurisdiction & "','" & _
        Me.TxtTaxType & "','" & Me.TxtAcctNo & "','" & Me.TxtFrequency & "','" & _
        Me.txtFileMeth & "','" & Me.txtPymtMeth & "','" & _
        Me.TxtMonth & "','" & Me.TxtDueDate & "','" & Me.TxtPrep & "','" & Me.TxtReviewer & "')"

    FileInfosubform.Form.Requery
```